# Is it possible to trigger a flyout from a navigation view item?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'd like to trigger a flyout from my navigation view item to extend it one level further.  Sort of a second level navigation item.  Nothing I've tried seems to work.

I tried adding a context flyout this way

```
<NavigationViewItem Content="List" Tag="SamplePage1" >
    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        <SymbolIcon Symbol="List"/>
    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
    <NavigationViewItem.ContextFlyout>
        <Flyout>
            <TextBlock>Hello World</TextBlock>
        </Flyout>
    </NavigationViewItem.ContextFlyout>
</NavigationViewItem>
```

I've also tried using `FlyoutBase` with no luck

```
<NavigationViewItem Content="List" Tag="SamplePage1" >
    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        <SymbolIcon Symbol="List"/>
    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <Flyout>
            <TextBlock>Hello World</TextBlock>
        </Flyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</NavigationViewItem>
```

Comment: I am not sure if it can be done with `NavigationView`  but you can use `SplitView` which provide more customization options. Also for adding flyout to `SplitView' you can refer [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8b6ecd92-be7c-4d7c-a3bf-1bcdc941534c/uwpxaml-splitview-menu-with-submenu?forum=wpdevelop) link.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up going with a popup that slides in from the side.

Comment: @Smeegs Can you please provide a brief guide on how you did that?